# functions and writing procedures

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hello everyone
I am still working on this. I have a few questions. I am starting to understand a little more. The only question I dont understand is this...

> From the main procedure call a
>   function procedure which calculates
>   and returns a value for the
>   “hypotenuse” equal to the square root
>   of (x squared + y squared).  You will
>   have to pass the values of x and y to
>   this function procedure.  The
>   procedure should calculate and return
>   a double type value.  The value that
>   is returned by this function procedure
>   should be equal to the square root of
>   (x squared + y squared). Also from the
>   main procedure call a sub procedure to
>   display the values of x, y, and the
>   hypotenuse.

This just through me off. here is what i have so far.Now would i declare this in the x or should I have x and y together?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim x As Double = width()
    Dim y As Double = height(x)
    Console.Read()
End Sub
Private Function width() As Double
    Dim x As Double
    x = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
    Return x
End Function
Private Function height(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Dim y As Double
    y = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())
    Return y
End Function
Private Sub hypotenuse(ByVal x As Double, ByVal y As Double)
    y = Math.Sqrt(x squared + y squared)
    Console.WriteLine(x & " X = " & y & " Y")
End Sub


End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the width and height. Now you need to calculate the hypotenuse - you already have the formula, you just need to translate that into code (as this is homework, I'm not going to give it :-) ). Store the result in another Double.

Then call a procedure (that you still need to create) where you pass the three values and print them (Console.Write / Console.WriteLine).

Answer (score 0):

`(x squared + y squared)` only makes sense in the problem statement and **is not legal vb code**. You will need to convert this to a working expression.

I also don't like how you do `y = the hipotenuse`. Create a new variable instead of clobbering your inputs. (since you also want to use x and y latter as shown by the `Console.Writeline`)